gitlab-ci replace parent variable by children values
My parent file:
.dev_vars: &dev_vars {}

deploy-dev:
  variables:
    <<: *dev_vars
  script:
  - echo "URL=$URL"

My child file:
include:
  - project: 'ci-parent'
    ref: 'main'
    file: 
      - my-gitlab-ci.yml 

.dev_vars: &dev_vars
  URL: http://my-dev_url

URL value is empty, I expected it to be http://my-dev_url

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors

You can’t use YAML anchors across multiple files when using the
include keyword. Anchors are only valid in the file they were defined
in.

It is because the parent file is rendered first, and then it is included in the child file.
Therefore, the final rendered child file looks like this:
".dev_vars":
  URL: http://my-dev_url
deploy-dev:
  variables: {}
  script:
  - echo "URL=$URL"

To resolve the issue without touching the structure, global variables can be used:
child file:
include:
  - project: 'ci-parent'
    ref: 'main'
    file: 
      - my-gitlab-ci.yml 

variables:
  URL: http://my-dev_url

and then it works as needed.
